# Windows Phone 8.1 Application Deployment Error

Tags: c#, sqlite, visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8.1

I added SQL database to my windows phone 8.1 application and now I cant deploy my app to my lumia 520 or any windows devices, I need Help! The following is the error:-

**Error 1   The processor architecture of the project being built "Any CPU" is not supported by the referenced SDK "Microsoft.VCLibs, Version=12.0". Please consider changing the targeted processor architecture of your project (in Visual Studio this can be done through the Configuration Manager) to one of the architectures supported by the SDK: "x86, ARM".   MyProject.WindowsPhone
I did try that but when I put it to ARM it gives me the following error**

And When I change the config to ARM:-

**Error 1- There was a mismatch between the processor architecture of the project being built "ARM" and the processor architecture, "x86", of the implementation file "C:\Users\john\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\TheBeat\packages\Sqlite-Winrt.3.8.7.1\lib\wpa81\SQLiteWinRT.dll" for "C:\Users\john\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\TheBeat\packages\Sqlite-Winrt.3.8.7.1\lib\wpa81\SQLiteWinRT.winmd". This mismatch may cause runtime failures. Please consider changing the targeted processor architecture of your project through the Configuration Manager so as to align the processor architectures between your project and implementation file, or choose a winmd file with an implementation file that has a processor architecture which matches the targeted processor architecture of your project.MyProject.WindowsPhone**

And When the Config is x86

**Error : DEP3311 : Unable to deploy an x86 package to a Windows Phone device. Change the build configuration to ARM or Neutral or change the Debug Target to an emulator.TheBeat.WindowsPhone**

Comment: Did you try deploying to the Emulator as suggested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make sure the configuration(Any CPU, x86, x64, ARM) of the application and the configuration of the References are the same. If not sure how to do that make sure while adding the references the application is in the Configuration you want it in.

Answer (score 1):

I solved my query, If such an error occurs make sure the configuration(Any CPU, x86, x64, ARM) of the application and the configuration of the References are the same. If not sure how to do that make sure while adding the references the application is in the Configuration you want it in.

Comment: how to see the configuration of the References?

Answer (score 0):

in my case I have Error: Could not find SDK “Microsoft.VCLibs, version=12.0”.
I just copy folder 
“c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1\ExtensionSDKs\Microsoft.VCLibs”
to
“c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\WindowsPhoneApp\v8.1\ExtensionSDKs\Microsoft.VCLibs”
and all ok.
p.s. I'm write this comment for googler's, because this page in top position on this problem. Thanks.
p.s.s. Reinstall VS/Repair VS/Update VS to v3/WP8.1 SDK's - don't help. Only help copying folder.